# .ssh/environment does not work on Synology dsm3.2. How to fix/debug?

Tags: git, nas, sshd

I'm trying to set up git on Synology NAS via ssh.
I've created git user, set private key authentication and installed git package.
I can log in successfully using private keys and have git in /opt/bin working locally (on NAS).

To make it work I changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config to have:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes                                                   
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys                               

PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

But I still can't make it work remotely.

The problem seem to be in path used by ssh when I execute remote commands. I can confirm that because when I do

```
ssh gitowner@nas.home echo \$PATH
```

I get

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/syno/bin
```

which is different from interactive shell which is giving me:

```
PATH='/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
```

I created .ssh/environment with following content

```
PATH='/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
```

but it still doesn't resolve the problem. Looks like its contents is not read.

I tried with environment file permissions set to -rw------- and -rw-r--r-- but also to no avail.

What else I could be missing sshd(?) in configuration that prevents it from reading user environment?

Comment: Are the double quotes actually in your `.ssh/environment` file?

Comment: No not really, i'll update the question. I might have tried that in despair.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to try to run ssh in debug mode by running in on another port:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -D -p 222
```

then running client with

```
ssh -v -p 222
```

and it became visible that it actually picks up environment. The problem was that NAS's ssh restart script

```
/usr/syno/etc/rc.d/S95sshd.sh restart
```

did't really restarted sshd, but only dropped existing connections and it failed to reread config. Once restarted, config was picked up and everything started to work.